# Modifying commands defined by the article class document

Tags: document-classes, article, documentclass-writing

So I am trying to add or take out a few lines to the already existing article class file to make a something like a `NEWarticle.cls`. The original class I used the following command lines, which gives me the image below:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{KSOlecture}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\slshape\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\slshape\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\oldstylenums{\thepage}}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\scriptsize\copyright\oldstylenums{\the\year} Name}
\fancyhfoffset[RE,LO]{\oddsidemargin}
\fancyhfoffset[RO,LE]{\marginparwidth}
\fancypagestyle{first}{
 \fancyhf{}
 \fancyfoot[R]{\scriptsize\copyright\oldstylenums{\the\year} Name}
 \fancyfoot[C]{\oldstylenums{\thepage}}
 \fancyfootoffset{\marginparwidth}
 \fancyheadoffset{0pt} }
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.25pt}

\newcommand{\Com}[1]{\smash{\tikz[baseline=(C.base)]
            \node[rectangle,draw,thin,minimum width=1.3em,minimum height=1.3em,inner sep=0pt] (C) {#1};}}

\begin{document}
\title{The Postulates of Quantum Mechanics}
\author{}
\date{\oldstylenums{17}--\oldstylenums{29} January \oldstylenums{\the\year}}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{first}

Blah blah blah...
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to do a `renewcommand` type of thing in the original article class `\maketitle` command to make something exactly like the following image:

[image]

An example would be:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
%other commands and packages...
\begin{document}
\lecturenumber{30} %I want it to use the \Com command
\title{Quantum Mechanics: Motivation and Paradoxes}
\author{}
\date{\oldstylenums{17}--\oldstylenums{29} January \oldstylenums{\the\year}}
\sources{stuff stuff stuff} %Probably use a description environment
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{first}

STufffffff
\end{document}
```

To Clarify: There is a section of coding in the article.cls that creates the title page. I want to modify those codes a little to create the image with the citations on it. In order to make the changes to the article.cls, I would have to create a new class that would be titled NEWarticle.cls instead. So, my question is how do I change the definitions and styles set by the article class, in order to make what I want?

Comment: Your write-up would seem to suggest that you're looking for a software-based method to change the title string `The Postulates of Quantum Mechanics` automatically to `Quantum Mechanics: Motivation and Paradoxes`. Please clarify what your objectives may be.

Comment: @Mico I clarified the question a little more at the bottom. Those are just example titles. I want anything encased in \title{...} to be printed in bold and large.